# Terraform: pass variable list to container environment variables

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, terraform

I am trying to find a way how to pass/map the list variable to *kubernetes_deployment* container environment variables. I run an asp.net core application in the container and I trying to modify the app with setting env variables to override the app settings.json. It is not a problem to override single values from settings.json, the problem is if I need to define/override the whole array there.

I have variable list like this in terrafrom:

```
variable "allowed_cars" {
  type = list(
      object({
      manufacturer  = string
      model  = string
    })
  )
}
```

Then, I have resource definition of *kubernetes_deployment* with containers.

I believe it could work if I set the env variables for the container like this:

```
env {
   name  = "App__AllowedCars__0__Manufacturer"
   value = "xxx"
}
env {
   name  = "App__AllowedCars__0__Model"
   value = "xxx"
}
env {
   name  = "App__AllowedCars__1__Manufacturer"
   value = "xxx"
}
env {
   name  = "App__AllowedCars__1__Model"
   value = "xxx"
}
...
```

Is there a way how to pass these env variables to the container in a dynamic way based on *allowed_cars* terraform variable? I don't know how many items will be defined for each environments, etc...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you read https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html?

Comment: yes, that works, thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to consider writing up what you did as a self answer to this question so that others might also benefit from what you've done here.

Answer (score 2):

Something of this definition (used example of `azurerm_container_group` in azure)

`environment_variables = "${merge(var.env_vars,var.secure_env_vars,local.master_env)}"`

and then variables can be passed in

```
variable "env_vars" {
  type = "map"
  description = "envvaars"

  default = {
    WEB_USER         = "locust"
    HATCH_RATE       =  25
    LOCUST_COUNT     =  50
    LOCUST_FILE      = "/locust/locustfile.py"
    ATTACKED_HOST    = "https://api-perf.yrdy.com"
  }
}

variable "secure_env_vars" {
  type = "map"
  description = "secure env vars"

  default = {
    WEB_PASSWORD     = "dummy"
    API_KEY          = "test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ydaetskcoR mentioned, the *dynamic* block was solution for me.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

```
dynamic "env" {
   for_each = var.allowed_cars
   content {
      name = "App__AllowedCars__0__${env.key}__Manufacturer"
      value = env.value["manufacturer"]
   }
}
```